# cvs - how do I find out if I need a new directory without `cvs up`?

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have written a shell script to show me what files need patching without actually doing a `cvs up`. It's just a simple `cvs stat` parser.

But, it doesn't tell me if a new directory would come down with a new `cvs up -d`.

Is there a way to find out if I'm missing directories that would be created with the next `cvs up -d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-n` switch shows me missing directories:

```
cvs -n up -d
```

The `-n` switch does not actually run `cvs up -d`; it just shows the effects of running the command.